# Map all files and objects of a django Project

Tags: python, django

Currently, I'm starting to work on a Django project which it's already begun.

Don't misunderstand me, I already know how basic files and dependencies work and relate to each other on this framework (forms, views, models, urls, templates, etc)

But my problem is, that this is a project with lots of files, classes, models, constants, etc... And has lots of code not written by myself.

I'm not very familiar to these internal custom objects, so, I need a module or script on python which can read all folders and map all relationships and dependencies (internal project objects, not modules or requirements), so I can better understand what's already done and work more efficiently on these modifications I have to do.

Currently I'm studying it manually, but it's very unefficient, and a slow process, so, if anyone knows about a tool or maybe a script, of these characteristics, please let me know where I can find it, download it, etc...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try googling for keywords like "python dependency graph", which can yield e.g. [snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/). Also any tool you might find won't save you the trouble of actually reading the code :-) The best tool that works for me is pen&paper to extend my short term memory as I read.

Comment: Yes! Of course I need to read it :), but hey, too many dependencies, I need at least a map, lol, let me try :) Thanks!

Comment: graphing models can be done through http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/graph_models.html

Comment: Yes, but I'm under windows, pygraphviz doesn't compiles under this environment, although there is solution to that here on SO, going to check it, thank you

Comment: Ok @dm03514 I manage to make it, outside virtualenv on win x32, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Python has a builtin module called [modulefinder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/modulefinder.html) that can be run from the command line to trace dependencies. It can be invoked like

```
python -m modulefinder mymodule.py
```

to print module dependencies of mymodule.py